# Magento multiple address checkout confirmation page blank

Tags: checkout, confirmation

As i checkout my shopping cart, the Multiple Address Checkout Confirmation isn't working properly

when hit 'place order' button, it shown blank page and the url redirect to :

```
http://local.mydomain.com/checkout/multishipping/overview/ --> http://local.mydomain.com/checkout/multishipping/overviewPost/
```

instead

```
http://local.mydomain.com/checkout/multishipping/overview/ --> http://local.mydomain.com/checkout/multishipping/success
```

did anyone had experienced this issue, also have solve the problem,

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the action `overviewPostAction` is the correct one to be called. This action will process your orders and then forward to the success page when there is no error or back to the page that is causing the order not to be valid.

But you appear to have an error somewhere, without code or an error message it is tough to help out. Try the following for general debug advice.

[Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while upgrading the magento.

So I debug the Multishipping controller in `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\MultishippingController.php`. So its redirecting back to address because the `!$this->_validateFormKey()` condition in `overviewPostAction` is fails(Thanks for @david-manners).

After upgrading i used the same theme file. So the formkey is not added in the `app\design\frontend\[theme]\template\checkout\multishipping\overview.phtml` file

So I added the `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` next to `<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return showLoader();">` in `app\design\frontend\[theme]\template\checkout\multishipping\overview.phtml`.

It solves my problem. Hope it will help some other.

Thanks.